# oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT vs. oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g

I tried setting `oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT` as connection properties but it seems like it is not working,
however setting `oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout` works. Any idea why? I am using 11g JDBC Drivers. And the DB server version is 11g.

Answer (score 6):

According to http://www.javamonamour.org/2012/09/oraclenetconnecttimeout.html

> **`oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT`** for jdbc versions `< 10.1.0.5` **`oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout`** for jdbc versions `>=10.1.0.5`

So if you are using a JDBC driver version 10.1.0.5 or higher, then `oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout` is the correct property.

Answer (score 0):

try reading the Oracle Document "How to Ensure that JDBC Queries are Always Timed Out (Doc ID 559564.1)"
They suggest using one of these properties:

```
for the Thin driver:  oracle.net.ns.SQLnetDef.TCP_CONNTIMEOUT_STR
for the OCI driver:  sqlnet.outbound_connection_timeout
```

I haven't tested myself so I cannot guarantee it actually solves the issue.