# Hybris Transaction Timeout

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How to set Hybris db transaction timeout using oracle database?

I have tried the following code but no effect, thanks in advance.

```
TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate(manager);
template.setTimeout(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set in local.properties `db.connectionparam.oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout` or `db.connectionparam.oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT` (both in millisecond).

Check this post for the difference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18513472/1140748

To explain a bit, in the platform, in `AbstractTenant` you have a method `extractCustomDBParams` that checks for key starting with `db.connectionparam` .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this setting is for individual statement timeout, it is difference with spring transaction timeout that allow execute multiple statements within the timeout I set.